# How to create an organised association that is project oriented?

Tags: agile, team-management, project-team, scheduling, team-building

A group of youngsters (age average of 20 years) would like to establish an organisation that makes projects into reality. The question would be: What kind of structure would be the best to manage this organisation of about 32 people with different talents and specialties varying from Tech to Management?

I'd like examples of professional organizations that are project oriented and handles a lot of projects at the same time. I'd like our organization to be able to adapt to changes in the social scene in addition to changes in our economic state. I would also like to know a way to get us heavy sponsors?

I'd like to know everything there is to build a project team and how to maintain it including the tasks of every member of the team, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is the project's perspective. You as an organisation shall sit down and **check each project and figure out what kind of expertise the project requires and on which level**. Have smaller groups, and each group should to a list for each project. When they are finished, they should compare their lists and come up with a common settings.

Now, you know what you need, it is time to see what you have. Ask people to put their names next to a project based on their knowledge and interest.

You or the CEO/CTO should know the priority of the projects, and with the lists above it should be visible if you are able to start working on them or not. In case you don't have enough expertise to start, you can check the interest. Or, in case you have more people, you as an organisation can start arguing on how to distribute yourself.

When a project is ready, you can start this procedure again.

Another approach would be - which I like better - is to have cross functional teams. Such a team should have a knowledge to handle any kinds of project within your domain. You can form this team with the "who would like to work with whom" approach. Of course the cross functionality trumps personal preferences when the team lacks a certain quality.

I favour the second option because the team can stay together and there will less time spent on "forming and storming", and this kind of team learns faster than a changing one. The first option does not care much about people and their preferences, therefore it is kind of a short term or emergency solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to determine up front what the organisational structure and roles will be will be, why not allow them to self-organise?

Create multi-discipline teams. Research has shown that a good team size is in the range 3-9 people. Bigger than that and communication can become a problem. Maybe 4-5 teams would be a good number for your organisation?

Once you have the teams organised, create a clear backlog of work for each team. This is best done by working closely with your customers/users. Or possibly by creating a 'Product Owner' type role that is responsible for collating requirements and determining their priority.

Now the teams can set to work on the backlog. Suggest to them that they meet regularly (say once per week or once per fortnight) to discuss how things are going. Then allow them to adjust their process, organisation and roles to reflect what they have learned.

Get the teams to talk together regularly so they can share their experience and their approach.

That's it. Inspect and adapt. If the teams decide they want to use a formal framework like Scrum or Prince 2 then they can bring it in. But let the process be pulled in to the teams by their needs rather than starting with a process and having the teams forced to adapt to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to show briefly my approach:

1. learn about team members (both: (hard & soft) skills; and team roles (Belbin's approach) ) - make internal 360 assesment and draw matrix
2. learn and agree about tools & techniques (PMOBK, SCRUM,  etc..)
3. learn and agree about procedures (especially decision making and motivation)
4. fill (at least) project roaster and risk estimats for every project
5. make dashboard for all projects
6. make idea board

every 3 months make follow up to improve Your teams processes